# Modal window doesn't open in django

Tags: python, django

I'm having a little problem with a modal in django. When I click on the button to open the modal window just nothing happens. I'm a beginner, so don't swear too much at very stupid mistakes.

```
{% extends 'main/layout.html' %}

{% block title %} Registration {% endblock %}

{% block content %}

    <div class="features">
        <h1> Registration </h1>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open modal window</button>
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" role = "dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"> Form </h5>
                        <button class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>Something</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <form method = "post">

            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.name }}<br>
            {{ form.mail }}<br>
            {{ form.phone }}<br>
            {{ form.password }}<br>
            <font color="red">{{error}}</font><br> <br>
            <button class = "btn btn-success" type = "submit">add news</button>
        </form>


    </div>



{% endblock %}
```

Pattern

```
{% load static %}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>{% block title %} {% endblock %}</title>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.2.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'main/css/main.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.2/css/all.css">
</head>
<body>
    <aside>
        <img src="{% static 'main/img/1.jpg' %}" alt="Logo">
        <span class="logo">Rolex</span>
        <h3>Навигация</h3>
        <ul>
            <a href="{% url 'home' %}"><li><i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i> Главная</li></a>
            <a href="{% url 'about' %}"><li><i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i> Про нас</li></a>
            <a href="{% url 'news_home' %}"><li><i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i> Новости </li></a>
            <a href=""><li><i class="fa-solid fa-book"></i> Контакты</li></a>
            <a href="{% url 'create' %}"><li> <button class = "btn btn-info"> <i class="fa-solid fa-plus"> Добавить запись </i> </button> </li></a>
        </ul>
    </aside>
    <main>
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </main>
    
</body>
</html>
```

I looked at different sites and tried to do what is written there, but I did not understand what I was doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try including `bootstrap.bundle.min.js` instead of `bootstrap.min.js`

so instead of using

`<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.2.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

use

`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>` or
`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>`
any other link that provide `bootstrap.bundle.min.js`

**EDIT:**

in bootstrap 5 the name of data attributes are changed
use the `button` below

`<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#myModal">Open modal window</button>`

data-toggle -> data-bs-toggle

data-target -> data-bs-target

Comment: It's not working. The modal window doesn't open.

Comment: try adding the script at the end of html page, instead of <head> tag, and do checkout edited answer

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for trying to help. It didn't work, but this one did
I added these 2 lines in Pattern
`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

and I launch the window with this thing

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.hhh').click('load',function(){
        $('#ModalExample').modal('show');
    });

</script>
```